# Reset background color for QTabWidget

Tags: background-color, qtabwidget, qt5.6

I see that QTabWidget background color is lighter than container widget. How to set its background to same as container widget has? Or better make it transparent?

I have following code:

```
  tabWidget->setPalette(palette());
  tabWidget->setBackgroundRole(backgroundRole());
  tabWidget->setStyle(style());  // Set parent widget style

  QPalette pal = tabWidget->palette();
  pal.setColor(QPalette::Base, palette().background().color());
  tabWidget->setPalette(pal);
```

which worked for me with QTreeWidget, however does not work for QTabWidget. Why Qt makes it different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by setting `autoFillBackground` to `true` in UI. However tabs titles background still white - any way to solve?